# Word for when you're so angry that your head starts hurting

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the condition when you're so angry that your head starts hurting?

E.g.:

> This story is so ______.

The word should include that you're having a headache. We have it in our language, and I'm wondering if English has a similar word. There are many words for anger but they just modify the intensity not add this meaning like furious.

Comment: Can you add a situation in  a few sentences that describes thins? Your title and your content sound like two different situations? Also, give a sentence with a blank where you think the word would fit.

Comment: The example sentence is about the story, and the question is about the person. Can you clarify?

Comment: Your head starts pounding or throbbing. This story is so headache inducing.

Comment: @jimm101 the story is enraging a person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a word for the condition when you're so angry that your head starts hurting?

No.

A close word is apoplectic

MW:

> **apoplectic** adjective
>
> Definition of apoplectic
>
> 1 medical : of, relating to, or causing apoplexy or stroke
>
> also : affected with, susceptible to, or showing symptoms of apoplexy or stroke**
> *NOTE: Use of apoplectic in medical contexts relating to stroke still occurs but is now generally considered dated.*
>
> :2 a: of a kind to cause or apparently cause stroke** - an apoplectic rage
>
> **2 b: extremely enraged = "He was apoplectic over the news**

i.e. So angry you could have a stroke.

The idea is that if you are angry, your blood pressure rises: if you blood pressure rises, you may have a stroke (apoplexy.)

This story <s>is so</s> makes me **apoplectic**.